# I have installed pipwin but having trouble in installing pyaudio,showing pipwin is not recognizable

Tags: numpy, pip, speech-recognition, python-3.8, pyaudio

PS C:\Users\adity\Desktop\Python project> pip install pipwin
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pipwin in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pySmartDL>=1.3.1; python_version >= "3.4" in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.9.0 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: js2py in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (0.70)
Requirement already satisfied: pyprind in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipwin) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2; python_version >= "3.0" in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4>=4.9.0->pipwin) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->pipwin) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->pipwin) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->pipwin) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->pipwin) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal>=1.2 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from js2py->pipwin) (2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjsparser>=2.5.1 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from js2py->pipwin) (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from packaging->pipwin) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tzlocal>=1.2->js2py->pipwin) (2020.1)
PS C:\Users\adity\Desktop\Python project> pipwin install pyaudio
pipwin : The term 'pipwin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pipwin install pyaudio
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipwin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`enter code here`
  ```

---

### Heading

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error with the path.
what happens when you type `where pipwin` in cmd?
If the output is something like this

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

then try adding pipwin to PATH or reinstall pipwin.

```
pip install pipwin
```

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?